# Errors updating a record in Python

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to do a simple update in python. This the code I try to run:

```
 mycursor = mydb.cursor()
 if(result<5):
        os.remove(destiny)
        print(result)
        print(fi[:-4])
        print(lastid)
        sql = "UPDATE googlesearch SET similarity=%s WHERE tweetid=%d and imageName=%s"
        value = (str(result),lastid,str(fi[:-4]))
        print(value)
        mycursor.execute(sql, value)
        mydb.commit()
```

As you can see it is very easy. But when I run it, I have this error:

```
ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Printing values, I have this: 
    ('2.82258064516129', 2636, 'dimg_10')
And working in Navicat with this sentence, everything is perfect. So why, I have this error?.

Comment: Statement parameters positions are indicated by `%s`, not `%d`.

Comment: @khelwood That's an answer, not a comment

Comment: @pppery Yeah, I know. Bad habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement parameter positions are indicated by `%s`, not `%d`.

So I think if you change

```
sql = "UPDATE googlesearch SET similarity=%s WHERE tweetid=%d and imageName=%s"
                                                            ^
```

to

```
sql = "UPDATE googlesearch SET similarity=%s WHERE tweetid=%s and imageName=%s"
                                                            ^
```

you will avoid this error.